# MYSQL/PHP Input Variable Not producing desired results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a simple select query of a mysql database with PHP where two variables are set based on user input. One variable is a month and thus can only be one specific value at a time. The other is dynamic and can either be a specific value or all values in the table. The code looks similar to this:

```
$var1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Month'])) {
   $var1 = $_GET['Month'];
}
$var2 = $_GET['Person'];
if ($var2 == "All") {
   $var2 ="('Person 1' or 'Person 2' or 'Person 3')";
}
$query= sprintf("Select * from Table where `Month` = %s and `Person` = %s", GetSQLValueString($var1, "text"), GetSQLValueString($var2, "text"));
```

When I input a specific person for $var2 I am able to get the correct results, however, when I input All for $var2, the code runs but I return no results.

Actual block of code:

```
$colname_chainsales = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Period'])) {
  $colname_chainsales = $_GET['Period'];
}
$rep = $_GET['Rep'];
if ($rep == "All") {
    $rep = " 1=1 ";
} else {
    $rep = " `PSIP` = ".$_GET['Rep'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_PPSC, $PPSC);
$query_chainsales= sprintf("select `PSIP` as `Sales Rep`, `Month`, `chainsales`.`PPSC #` as `PPSC #`, `chainsales`.`Store Name` as `Store Name`, sum(`Sales Less Credits ($)`) as `Sales Less Credits ($)`, sum(`RX Sales`) as `RX Sales`, sum(`Brand RX`) as `Brand RX`,sum(`Brand Rx C2`) as `Brand Rx C2`,sum(`prnr sales`) as `prnr`,sum(`h2h sales`) as `h2h`,sum(`specialty sales`) as `Specialty`,sum(`Brand RX`)-sum(`Brand Rx C2`)- sum(`specialty sales`)-sum(`h2h sales`)  as `Net Brand`, sum(`Pro w/SG`) as `Pro w/SG` , sum(`Pro w/o SG`) as `rpro`, SUM(`Pro w/SG`) / (SUM(`RX Sales`)- SUM(`specialty sales`))* 100 AS `Compliance` from `chainsales` inner join `clients` on `chainsales`.`ppsc #`=`clients`.`ppsc #` WHERE `Month` = %s and %s Group by `PPSC #`, `Month` ORDER BY `PSIP`", GetSQLValueString($colname_chainsales, "text"), GetSQLValueString($rep, "text"));
$chainsales = mysql_query($query_chainsales, $PPSC) or die(mysql_error());
$row_chainsales= mysql_fetch_assoc($chainsales);
$totalRows_chainsales = mysql_num_rows($chainsales);
```

Comment: Great! Did you have any specific questions or?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Not even the escape functions are 100% injection safe.

Comment: Column names should be surrounded by back ticks and string values should be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: First of all, error in your query. `'Month', 'Person'`. Remove single quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Sorry about not including the question, first post in all. When I input All for $var2, I should get getting a result displaying everything from Table, while instead I return no results. Also, I am not worried about SQL Injections at this time as this is only for internal use and can not be accessed by anyone outside the company.

Comment: `$_Get['Person']` PHP variables are case-sensitive; did you mean `$_GET['Person']`? For that matter, why have the else-case at all?

Comment: _"I am not worried about SQL Injections at this time"_ - The famous last words. Later on, you will copy/paste your functions/queries for another project or this app gets released in public and you will forget to fix it. And, if any value contains a single quote or ends with a backslash, your query will fail, either way. Plus,you wouldn't even need your `sprinf` and your `GetSQLValueString()` functions if you used Prepare Statements.

Comment: @Frailtub you should always design systems using proper code, such as protecting yourself against SQL Injection, there is no point in doing it **wrong** and then going back later to fix it as it's very easy to forget to do, and eventually the project may become too big to do so easily. Trust me on this one.

Comment: Made edited to the original post to fix typos in the code. It was not copy and pasted. This isn't a project I am starting but adding a functionality to a project that was created by someone else years ago. I would be rebuilding the entire thing from scratch to prevent SQL Injection. I removed the else statement as it was redundant.

Comment: If you want to fetch all if `$var2` contains "All", then just remove the `Person` statement from the query completely in that case.

Comment: Btw, isn't `GetSQLValueString()` an old DreamWeaver-generated function that escapes the inputs? Then you can't have quotes and stuff in those strings since they will be escaped. Do a `var_dump($sql)` and see what the query actually looks like when it's generated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator in place of `=` in your query like so:

```
Select * from Table where 'Month' = %s and 'Person' in %s", GetSQLValueString($var1, "text"), GetSQLValueString($var2, "text")
```

Also, when you define `$var2` as the list of people, change "or" to commas:

```
if ($var2 == "All") {
   $var2 ="('Person 1', 'Person 2' , 'Person 3')";
} else {
   $var2 ="('".$_Get['Person']."')" ;
}
```

Comment: Suppose, `$var2 == "All"` case. Then, query will become `Person in ('Person 1' or 'Person 2' or 'Person 3')`. Which Is Wrong.

Comment: Your column names should be surrounded by backticks, not single quotes

Answer (score 0):

**Changes**

1. Enclose column name using *backtick* instead of *single quotes*.
2. Change `$var2` value on basis of it's condition.

***Edit-1***

Suppose,

*Case-1:* `$var2 = "All"`:: Query will append to `IN` operator.

*case-2:* `$var2 = 1`:: Query will append to `=` operator.

**Updated Code**

```
$var1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Month'])) {
  $var1 = $_GET['Month'];
}

$var2 = $_GET['Person'];
if ($var2 == "All") {
  $var2 = " IN ('Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Person 3')";
} else {
  $var2 = " = ".$_GET['Person'];
}

$query= sprintf("SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Month` = %s and `Person` %s", GetSQLValueString($var1, "text"), GetSQLValueString($var2, "text"));
```

***Edit-2***

> **Reference to OP Comment:** When I input All for $var2, I should get getting a result displaying everything from Table,

```
$var1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Month'])) {
  $var1 = $_GET['Month'];
}

$var2 = $_GET['Person'];
if ($var2 == "All") {
  $var2 = " 1 = 1 ";
} else {
  $var2 = " `Person` = ".$_GET['Person'];
}

$query= sprintf("SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Month` = %s  AND %s", GetSQLValueString($var1, "text"), GetSQLValueString($var2, "text"));
```

Comment: Why not just remove the `Person`-statement completely in case all should be shown?

Comment: I can do that according to the requirement. Who knows, OP might have kept some restriction for other Persons too. Otherwise, we can remove that `IN ..` statement. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: It might been easy to miss since the OP only mentioned it in a comment: _"When I input All for $var2, I should get getting a result displaying everything from Table"_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Done. I Didn't saw that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This has worked in case 1 when the input is all, however, has broken the functionality of case 2 when a specific person is the input.

Comment: "*..has broken the functionality of case 2 when a specific person is the input.*" Broken in the sense? What error it displays @Frailtub

Comment: When a specific person is the input, it displays no results.

Comment: Have you checked the table name, column name? It should work, there is nothing where it will break @Frailtub. Which One you used Edit-1 or Edit-2?

Comment: I've updated my code. Please use my code once again. Modified `column name` in Edit-2 Section @Frailtub

Comment: Using Edit 2. I check everything. I can only assume that it is not passing the query correctly as the code executes, just does not return results.

Comment: Again check @Frailtub. Actually instead of `Person`, I used `person` in column name. Which I have corrected.

Comment: I checked. The code I submitted was a sample of what I was doing. Here is my actual code block. Added to original post.

Comment: I saw your actual code. What you can do is: `echo $query_chainsales; die;` Paste the output in your database table SQL and check what error is coming @Frailtub